# Why is the Facebook button only appears after all the images are loaded?

Tags: javascript, facebook, performance, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-like

This is not about loading Facebook asynchronously or any kind of optimization here but to load it as fast as possible rather than as slow as possible ;)

My website contains a LOT of images. And I need the Facebook Like button to show up as soon as possible. But it seems the button doesn't load: it waits for all the images to be loaded before loading itself. Since I have many images, of course the Like button shows up very late. If the connection is really slow, that might even take one minute. You can see the issue here: http://www.totorotimes.com.

Any idea how I could do this?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take all the javascript code that is for the social media buttons out of your `body` tags, put them in a file called: "social.js" and then insert that file right above all the js files in your`head` tag. This will make your buttons load before the actual web page loads.

Comment: Thank you! I actually end-up with moving the script by myself in the header above the others scripts.